# How to log specific exception if i am already using FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, exceptionhandler

I am using FullAjaxExceptionHandler to handle timeout issue in ajax request. The problem that I am facing is to handle javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException. If i have an error in the xhtml page, i dont want to show the stack trace instead show an error page. This i have achieved by specifying error page in web.xml. The problem is that i want to log this error. I am using log4j for other exceptions, but how to write handler for FaceletException. If write another Exception handler is there an order in which i should specify the handler class because i am already using FullAjaxExceptionHandler.

faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.ScheduleRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.domain.web.custom.MyScheduleRenderrer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom Exception handler factory in faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>com.fetchinglife.domain.web.permissions.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Create custom exception handler factory

```
public class CustomExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory{

private ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped;

public CustomExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped) {
    this.wrapped = wrapped;
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
    return new CustomExceptionHandler(wrapped.getExceptionHandler());
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandlerFactory getWrapped() {
    return wrapped;
}
```

}

Create custom exception handler

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler{

static Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(CustomExceptionHandler.class);

public CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
    super(wrapped);
}

@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
    if(unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.hasNext()){
        Throwable exception = unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.next().getContext().getException();
        log.error("FL Error",exception);
    }
    super.handle();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that you can't have both.

- From The JSF Spec, the `ExceptionHandlerFactory` is expecting a single type to be configured
- From the source of the [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java), if the exception is non-ajax, it's rethrown, to be handled by the `<error-page>` mechanism.

---

You'll either have to extend or wrap the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` to provide both Ajax and Non-Ajax exception handling

Comment: there was an answer by @baluc which I followed with a small change. It worked perfectly for me. Now when I when i want to make that the answer i cant find that answer. Did someone removed that answer.

Comment: @VineethNG maybe he removed it himself. If you have a working solution, you can post an answer yourself